# How to Insert Array values in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

Is it possible to insert the array values below in mysql?

```
foreach ($query->result() as $list)
{
    $fieldname  = $list->column_name;
    $fieldvalue = $_REQUEST[$list->column_name];

    echo $fieldname;
    echo $fieldvalue;
}
```

**Result**

The Echo Result of fieldname is: age Gender fullname

The Echo Result of fieldvalue is: 21 Female Carla

How Can I Insert these Values in MYSQL in their corresponding column name?

```
$query =  $this->db->query("insert into my_table
                      ($fieldname) values ('','$fieldvalue')");
```

Comment: Is `$fieldname` an array?

Comment: Hi Aldrin, fieldname is not an array anymore after foreach

Comment: string replace with comma like e.g age,gender,fullname and same apply to values and then fire insert query.

Comment: Thank you, that will work,  i havent thought of that .

Comment: Welcome. Glad to help you.

Comment: Thank you @RuchishParikh :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ruchish Parikh said, It may help you:

```
<?php
foreach ($query->result() as $list)
{
    $fieldname  = $list->column_name;
    $fieldvalue = $_REQUEST[$list->column_name];
    //$fieldname  = "age Gender fullname";
    //$fieldvalue = "21 Female Carla";

    /*
    echo $fieldname;
    echo $fieldvalue;
    The Echo Result of fieldname is: age Gender fullname
    The Echo Result of fieldvalue is: 21 Female Carla
    */

    $new_fieldnames = str_replace(" ", ", ", $fieldname);
    $new_fieldvalue = "'".str_replace(" ", "','", $fieldvalue)."'";

    //echo $new_fieldnames."<br><br><br>";
    //echo $new_fieldvalue."<br>";

    $sql = "insert into my_table
                      ($new_fieldnames) values ($new_fieldvalue);";    
    $query =  $this->db->query($sql);

}

?>
```

Comment: Hi hmd , thank you for this , I used rtrim($fieldname,','); instead

Comment: Agreed, Happy coding :)